# How to view detailed Licensing Info about Office 2013 Installation on Windows?

Tags: license, microsoft-office-2013

On my Windows 7 laptop I have installed Office 2013 32 bit.

In Windows 7, the command cscript slmgr.vbs /dlv shows detailed licensing information about Windows installation.

From various internet articles I understand that when this command is followed by ‘all’ i.e.  cscript slmgr.vbs /dlv  all   it shows all other MS Products like Office 2013. However on my laptop when I run this command thru an elevated command prompt, I get the same Windows 7 information repeated 3 – 4 times and there’s no information about Office 2013.

Some resources talk about passing activation id to this command in order to view Office 2013 related information.  I am not sure what activation id is?

What is the correct way to view detailed licensing information for the installed Office 2013 on my laptop?

Thanks.

Comment: This a retail key or a volume license, because the command doesn't work on a retail office key, and it only works on the KMS server when you got a volume license key...

Comment: It's a retail installation. Is it that the command is not applicable at all to retail? Is there any way to view the detailed licensing information in that case?

Comment: The command simply isn't applicable to retail copies of office